# Django-Import-Export: Import Error - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, csv, django-import-export

I'm trying to use the django-import-export package to import a csv into my django model. the csv is very simple, a header row and the one row of values. there are two fields on the csv that are defined in the model as DateField's

#models.py

```
edit_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Edit Date", blank=True, default="1970-01-01")
premiere_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Premiere Date", null=True, blank=True)
```

there are another set of DateTime.Field's in the model that are not included in the csv file. I have added header fields to the csv for these, but the csv hs no values for the fields.

```
created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
```

For the django-import-export package, I have a Resource class defined in my admin.py and it is working for exporting a csv. But when I try to import a csv - I get an Attribute Error.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'
```

The full traceback is listed below.

I've tried to fix this by adding a `before_save_instance` method to the Resource class.
But I'm still getting the same error. I've been through the docs and searched stack overflow, but I can't find a clear explanation of how to handle imports with the import-export package.

#admin.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
    instance.edit_date = parse(instance.edit_date).strftime('%y/%m/%d')        
    instance.premiere_date = parse(instance.premiere_date).strftime('%y/%m/%d')
    return instance
```

Not sure what else I need to do to get my import to work?
Does anyone see what I'm missing?

```
Line number: 1 - 'str' object has no attribute 'year'
, NGCI, 060171_25p_EM.mov, Europe's New Wild, Return of the Titans, 60171, -----, 7/6/20, Remote, Zach W, Jon B/Troy S, 01:00:00:00, 01:10:00:06, 00:10:00:06, 01:10:02:06, 01:18:58:09, 00:08:56:03, 01:19:00:09, 01:27:39:19, 00:08:39:10, 01:27:41:19, 01:34:04:19, 00:06:23:00, 01:34:06:19, 01:39:07:16, 00:05:00:22, 01:39:09:16, 01:44:10:00, 00:05:00:09, 00:00:00:00, 00:00:00:00, 00:00:00:00, 00:00:00:00, 00:00:00:00, 00:00:00:00, 00:00:00:00, 00:00:00:00, 00:00:00:00, 00:00:00:00, 00:00:00:00, 00:00:00:00, 00:44:10:00, 00:44:00:00, 01:45:10:00, 00:44:10:00, 6, 1080p, 25p, V:\Vantage_Watch\060171_25p_EM.mov, 0:00:00, 0:00:00, WJH101, 725380, INTL, INT, C, TVD, PROHQ, ENG, 178, ENG-51ST_DME-51ST_DME-Opt, 0, 7/6/20, , , , , , , , , , ,
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/ngceng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/widgets.py", line 183, in render
return value.strftime(self.formats[0])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/ngceng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 648, in import_row
    diff = self.get_diff_class()(self, original, new)
    File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/ngceng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.left = self._export_resource_fields(resource, instance)
    File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/ngceng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 229, in _export_resource_fields
    return [resource.export_field(f, instance) if instance else "" for f in resource.get_user_visible_fields()]
    File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/ngceng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 229, in <listcomp>
    return [resource.export_field(f, instance) if instance else "" for f in resource.get_user_visible_fields()]
    File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/ngceng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 849, in export_field
    return field.export(obj)
    File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/ngceng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/fields.py", line 125, in export
    return self.widget.render(value, obj)
    File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/ngceng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/import_export/widgets.py", line 185, in render
    return datetime_safe.new_date(value).strftime(self.formats[0])
    File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/ngceng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/datetime_safe.py", line 42, in new_date
    return date(d.year, d.month, d.day)
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the format in which the date is stored in the csv file.

Date string needs to be properly formatted or the date string should be converted to a proper date format

Convert date string to date obj

```py
from datetime import datetime


def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run): 
    format_str = '%d/%m/%y' # the format in which dates are stored in CSV file
    instance.edit_date = datetime.strptime(instance.edit_date, format_str)
    instance.premiere_date = datetime.strptime(instance.premiere_date, format_str)
    return instance
```

OR

In CSV file the dates should be in the format %Y-%m-%d

*Assuming that the `before_save_instance()` works as intended and the date in CSV file 7/6/20 is 7th of June 2020.*

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. I have tried both but unfortunately they give the same error.  I have also tried just add date values into the empty date fields  to see if that would make any difference, but that did not help either. I *really* wish the traceback would say exactly which field is the problem.